# hovering over elements triggering another element hover. What is the problem?

Tags: html, css

Relevant html:

```
<div class="bottom-page">
    <p>What is <span class="carmeet">CarMeet?</span></p>
</div>

<div class="definitions">

    <span class="n1"><p><span class="carmeet1">CarMeet</span> is the number 
  one website for fans of cars, and car enthusiasts alike.</p></span>

    <span class="n2"><p><span class="style2">Find</span> riders in your 
  local area, state, region, or country. <span class="style2">Cruise</span> 
 along.</p>

    <span class="n3"><p><span class="style2">Create</span> and <span 
 class="style2">Join</span> crews to drift along with. Stay up-to-date with 
your group <span class="style2">Online</span> or on <span 
class="style2">Adventures</span>.</p></span>

    <span class="n4"><p>Actively<span class="style2"> engage</span> in the 
 community through the online <span class="style2">forum</span>.</p></span>

    <span class="n5"><p><span class="style2">Coast</span> through countless 
   <span class="style2">news articles</span> to find out what else is 
  happening in 
   the <span class="style2">world of automobiles</span>, and find what's 
  available 
 on the <span class="style2">market</span>.</p></span>


</div>

</div>
```

Relevant css;

```
.n1:hover {
  outline-style: solid;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: black;
 }
 .n2:hover {
  outline-style: solid;
  background-color: lightblue;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: black;
 }
.n3:hover {
  outline-style: solid;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: black;
}
.n4:hover {
  outline-style: solid;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: black;
 }
 .n5:hover {
   outline-style: solid;
   background-color: #9558a0;
   opacity: 0.8;
   color: black;
 }
```

I'm sure theres been a hundred other questions regarding the same thing, but I can't seem to find one that helps my case. 
When I hover over n3-n5, it triggers n2. This does not happen when hovering n1.
Much appreciate, and sorry for being a noob.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

not close span tag on `<span class="n2">`

```
<span class="n2"><p><span class="style2">Find</span> riders in your 
  local area, state, region, or country. <span class="style2">Cruise</span> 
 along.</p></span>
```

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: That is still invalid HTML - you can not nest `p` into `span` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`n5`, `n4`, and `n3` all use the class `style2` in their children. 
Create different classes for each child span to have separate hover effects.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing one closing span on second one:

I have done the changes, please check also make span `display:block;`

```
<div class="bottom-page">
    <p>What is <span class="carmeet">CarMeet?</span></p>
</div>

<div class="definitions">

    <span class="n1"><p><span class="carmeet1">CarMeet</span> is the number 
  one website for fans of cars, and car enthusiasts alike.</p></span>

    <span class="n2"><p><span class="style2">Find</span> riders in your 
  local area, state, region, or country. <span class="style2">Cruise</span> 
      along.</p></span>

    <span class="n3"><p><span class="style2">Create</span> and <span 
 class="style2">Join</span> crews to drift along with. Stay up-to-date with 
your group <span class="style2">Online</span> or on <span 
class="style2">Adventures</span>.</p></span>

    <span class="n4"><p>Actively<span class="style2"> engage</span> in the 
 community through the online <span class="style2">forum</span>.</p></span>

    <span class="n5"><p><span class="style2">Coast</span> through countless 
   <span class="style2">news articles</span> to find out what else is 
  happening in 
   the <span class="style2">world of automobiles</span>, and find what's 
  available 
 on the <span class="style2">market</span>.</p></span>


</div>

</div>





.definitions > span {
  display: block;
}

.n1:hover {
  outline-style: solid;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: black;
}

.n2:hover {
  outline-style: solid;
  background-color: lightblue;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: black;
}

.n3:hover {
  outline-style: solid;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: black;
}

.n4:hover {
  outline-style: solid;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: black;
}

.n5:hover {
  outline-style: solid;
  background-color: #9558a0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The main problem was definitely that missing close span haha. whoops!

Comment: Welcome @Ewubbs :)